# how to display a stack of 5 blocks using recursive function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

I am doing an exercise with recursive function and I don't quite get it. I need to update a function

```
def draw_stack(screen, x, y, height):
    draw_block (screen, x, y)
```

In this function it should display a stack of 5 blocks in the screen anchored at the location x= 100, y =200.

How can I start this function? Can someone please explain how can I start my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw_stack(screen, x, y, height):
    draw_block (screen, x, y)    

for x in range(5): # This loop will run 5 times
       draw_stack(screen, 100, 200, 50)# This will run your function. You need to specify functions arguments.
```

I if you want to change values while running loop you can to this:

```
for x in range(5): # This loop will run 5 times
    draw_stack(screen, 100, 200+x, 50)# you can add or multiple any arg by x
```